# Can I make Bitcoin transactions without the involvement of a bank account whatsoever?

Tags: transactions, wallet, client

I am a web designer and I don't have access to a bank-account (and therefore, credit/debit-card) and I am not old enough to open a bank-account yet. Could I use a Bitcoin wallet to receive money and store it there as long as I want (and possibly, send those Bitcoins) ? Paypal would be ok except they only allow you to receive a limited amount before you are required to connect your Paypal account to a bank-account.

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! I see @Taurus you seem to have ended up with two user accounts. Please see [merging accounts](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) for assistance.

Comment: Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/13966/5406

Answer (score 2):

> Could I use a Bitcoin wallet to receive money and store it there as long as I want (and possibly, send those Bitcoins) ?

Yes. You can buy Bitcoin at Bitcoin ATM where is located some places. You can find a Bitcoin ATM [here](https://coinatmradar.com/).
Some ATMs allow you to buy and sell coins, but some does not allow you to sell.

Comment: (I am OP BTW) Thanks. However, I don't want to buy any Bitcoins! I only want to receive them, what I am asking is, can I trade in Bitcoin efficiently without the involvement of a bank-account ?

Comment: Yes. You can trade in Bitcoin without a bank account. However, the transaction fee is expensive ( if you want to get a confirmation in 10 mins, you probably have to pay $20+ for the fee). If you receive Bitcoin, you do not have to care the fee. You can check the average fee [here](https://bitcoinfees.earn.com/).

Comment: Thanks again. So, how do people get around these high transaction fees ? It sure is inefficient.

Comment: Those who afford high fees got involved in Bitcoin at an early stage, so they have a lot of bitcoin and made money with it. We can still send bitcoin with lower fees like $1 although it takes a few days to get a confirmation.

Comment: This is a big problem I never knew about. I did read somewhere though that the fees would get lower gradually (decades and years). And even worse, the confirmation problem, what are some possible solutions to this problem, aren't Bitcoin experts proposing any ?

Comment: Bitcoin core has been working on the scaling problem. You will be able to use [Lightning Network](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Lightning_Network) which allows you instant payment and low fees. LN is called off-chain solution. Bitcoin is a layer-one protocol, and LN is a layer-two protocol. You can think of LN as TCP/IP layer. On the other hand, Bitcoin cash came out in order to solve slow confirmations and high fees on-chain.

Comment: @Taurus Also, if (as you can in Bitcoin Core) you choose three-day target confirmation for the fee, instead of twenty minutes, then the fee rate is quite reasonable but, the transaction may take some time to confirm - choosing three-day target confirmation is not a guarantee of confirmation in three days. Usually, you can see a transaction soon after it is broadcast, just not confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize cash to purchase Visa, MasterCard or American Express prepaid gift cards, sell these for bitcoins, and then you can do the inverse when ready and sell the bitcoin for prepaid gift card which can be sold for cash.

A little bit of searching on the dark web; you can easily sell the prepaid gift cards for a bitcoins, for a small fee. Of course, before proceeding with any of this you’ll need to set up an off-line bitcoin wallet to have ready once you sell the prepaid gift cards for bitcoins.

When you’re ready to cash in your BitCoin you can simply do the exact inverse to extract bitcoin to prepaid gift card and then sell these for cash (a robust market for this on the dark web as well).

There you go: (cash > bitcoin | bitcoin > cash), with no Identification, bank accounts, debit/credit cards required.

Cheers

(Cashing out Bitcoin to cash using Peer to Peer sale locally is much easier to buy and sell cash to bitcoin and vice versa (e.g. localbitcoins.com); however, depending on the amount of money, it can be more dangerous then the method above)